# CSS - Background image not showing with no error

Tags: html, css, cordova

I've HTML, CSS, JS application working with cordova. I'm trying to show an whatsapp icon image on the page using CSS background image.

The image is loaded. However, the image isn't showing and the console doesn't show an error of image access forbidden, image not found, etc...

- I've tried to show image using `<img />` But with no use.
- I've tried using this css property : `background-size: contain !important;`
- I've tried to change `background-position` value.
- I've tried to use `background-image` in the inline css style of the element.
- I've tried adding text to `<a>` element.

None of them worked !

Here's My code :

```css
.whatsapp-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='theDownBar'>
  <a style='background-image: url(img/whatsapp-icon.png);' href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber' class='whatsapp-icon'></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT : Added some images to clarify**

The element is showing and has width and height

[image: The element is showing and has width and height]

There's no console error, and the image loaded successfully when I check the source
[image: There's no console error, and the image loaded successfully when I check the source]

Comment: did you check the link worked to the image  https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber .

Comment: Yup,
And If it wasn't working, It'll not make a difference I think.
As this link is only redirecting on click.
Not giving the image.

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry: add a link to working page where we can see 'loaded but hidden image'.

Comment: the link to the image ...... that's what the question is about :)  atranslucide png will show nothing, a partially translucide png might need a background-color to show its transparency ....

Comment: Edited,
Check for the new edit.

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry: add link to working page. We can't debug printscreen.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean to add link to working page.
But, when I run the code on codepen.It works normally.

Check this : https://codepen.io/AKhaled47/pen/ZNvqBB

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry: it means you have bad path to your image (linked relatively). Use absolute path or correct relative path to image. That's all.

Comment: Have you checked the images on the post ? If the image was not found or invalid, It'd have shown 404 error.

Besides, when using a link to the image, the problem stills the same.

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry: sorry, I really can't debug images. I'm telling you that there is bad path to image or the image is broken. You're telling that everything is okay, so... good luck, you're right! Ask us again soon! :-)

Comment: Do you think that there's a relate between this and Cordova ?

Comment: It's weird, Because other images are displaying normally.
This problem making me go nuts !

Comment: @panther Thanks man for help.
And sorry for wasting some of your time on this silly problem.
Fixed by clearing caches.

Answer (score 0):

Bro for me your code is working fine i just changed the image url see this:

```
<style>
.whatsapp-icon {
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<div class='theDownBar'><a style='background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-GuUP5Jaz3Rg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/HwaA1tNmtd0/photo.jpg);' href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber' class='whatsapp-icon'></a></div>
```

You should check it again but if it still didn't work then try this code:

```
<div class='theDownBar'>
<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber' class='whatsapp-icon'>
<img src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-GuUP5Jaz3Rg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/HwaA1tNmtd0/photo.jpg'/>
</a></div>
```

Don't forget to replace image url to your own.

Comment: Thanks for helping,
But, Still the same.

Comment: Can you share the url of that page if it is online.?

Comment: It's cordova IOS application,
Not online page.

Comment: Bro it seems that your image if not available or it is in invalid format.

Comment: No, It's not.
See the second image on the post.
It shows that console prints no error.

Comment: Thanks brother for help.
And sorry for wasting some of your time on this silly problem.
Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.whatsapp-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  display: block;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='theDownBar'>
  <a style="background-image: url('https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33447.png?size=1200x630f&pad=10,10,10,10&ext=png&bg=FFFFFFFF');"
     href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber' class='whatsapp-icon'></a>
</div>
```

i did this and its work! probably check your image is invalid!

Comment: Have you checked the images on the post ?
If the image was not found or invalid, It'd have shown 404 error